# Content disappears when adding a DataTemplate to a ContentPage in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, binding, scrollview

I have a simple ContentPage with a StackLayout and a child ScrollView. As soon as I add an Items Template and DataTemplate to the page, all other content disappears, even content, such as a Label, that doesn't even use the data from the bound data source.

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <!-- Body -->
            <ScrollView>
                <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding IdCardCollection }">
                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <!--<Label Text="{Binding IdCard.StateTerritoryCardTitle}" />-->
                            <Label Text="Test" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

```
    public partial class TestBinding : ContentPage
    {
        public TestBinding()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new TestIdCardViewModel(1);
        }
    }
```

```
    public class TestIdCardViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private IList<IdCard> _idCards;
        public ObservableCollection<IdCard> IdCardCollection { get; private set; }
        public IdCard IdCard { get; private set; }

        public TestIdCardViewModel()
        {
        }

        public TestIdCardViewModel(int maxListItems) : base(maxListItems)
        {
            _idCards = new List<IdCard>();

            CreateIdCardCollection(MaxListObjects);
        }

        private void CreateIdCardCollection(int maxListObjects)
        {
            _idCards.Add(new IdCard {StateTerritoryCardTitle = "Illinois - Proof of Auto Insurance" });

            IdCardCollection = new ObservableCollection<IdCard>(_idCards);

            IdCard = IdCardCollection.First();
        }
    }
```

```
    public class BaseViewModel
    {
        public int MaxListObjects { get; set; } = (int) NGICConstants.MaxListItems;

        public BaseViewModel()
        {
        }

        public BaseViewModel(int maxListItems)
        {
            // Save the List count limit.
            MaxListObjects = maxListItems;
        }
    }
```

No matter if I use the bound object or not, the Label does not appear. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are binding `ItemsSource` to `IdCard`, which is not an `IEnumerable`, it is just a single object

Comment: I changed it to bind to IdCardCollection, which is an ObservableCollection, and the Label still doesn't show up.

Comment: try `Text="{Binding StateTerritoryCardTitle}"`

Comment: With a few minor adjustments in my code, I did get this to work using the Binding you suggested. Thanks Jason.

Comment: @JNickVA1 Hi , you can update this in answer , then other people will know how to solve this . It will be helpful for others in SO :-)